# Spring MVC: RequestBody + ResponseEntity: How to return an object/entity without some of the obj fields

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to see is there a better way to achieve this: currently, I have a User class, UserRequest class and UserResponse class, they are all very similar or subset of User.

```
class User{
 long id;
 String name;
 String password;
 String field1;
 String[] array1;
}

class UserRequest{
 String name;
 String password;
}

class UserResponse{
 long id;
 String name;
 String field1;
}
```

So instead of having 3 similar classes, can I limit the fields using User class for the ResponseEntity? or what would be a better way to achieve what i am trying to do without having all the similar classes?

```
 public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<UserResponse> login(@RequestBody @Valid UserRequest request) {

  User user = userRep.findByPrimaryEmailLike(request.getPrimaryEmail());
  return new ResponseEntity<UserResponse>(user.getSuccessLoginResponse(), HttpHeaderUtils.getHeader4Json(), HttpStatus.OK);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your format and (de-)serialization handler is, but making the wild guess it's JSON via Jackson:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
class User {

    long id;
    String name;
    String password;
    String field1;
    String[] array1;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String[] getArray1() {
        return array1;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setArray1(String[] array1) {
        this.array1 = array1;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Affe. Still at least I need two similar classes? if you put the @JsonIgnore for the getPassword() method, for the RequestBody it won't get the password.

Comment: The getter and setter are configured independently.  You can ignore it when creating a response by marking the getter but still read it in when parsing a request by leaving the setter unmarked.

Comment: Ok, I have to add the @JsonProperty to the setter, otherwise the password doesn't get set!, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a SpringMVC extension like [Yoga](http://yoga.skyscreamer.org/), you can return only the User object, but customize the request to determine which fields are returned in the @ResponseBody. For example,

```
GET http://mydomain.com/user?selector=name,password

GET http://mydomain.com/user?selector=id,name,field1
```